# How does the term $a_7$ give? Are the calculations I have done for the other terms correct?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, differential

The Differential Equation

$y'' + ( p + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4}x^2)y=0$

where p is a constant, it has a series solution of the form

$y =\displaystyle\sum {a_n} x^n$ prove that:

a) the coefficients $a_n$ are related by the three-term recurrence formula

$(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}+( p + \frac{1}{2})$$a_n - \frac{1}{4}$$a_{n-2}=0 $

b) find its general solution by series $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ at least the first seven terms.

a)If we derive the series we have:

$y'= \sum na_nx^{n-1}$

$y''= \sum n( n-1)a_n x^{n-2} $

replacing in the D.E.
$ \sum n( n-1)a_n x^{n-2} + (p+ \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4}x^2) \sum a_n x^n = 0$
$\sum n(n-1)a_n x^{n-2}+ (p + \frac{1}{2}) \sum a_n x^n - \frac{1}{4} \sum a_n x^{n+2}=0$
looking at the coefficients of the power $x^m$ of degree $m$ in the first summation we take:
$n-2= m$
and in the last and remains:
$n+2=m$
$ (m+2)(m+1)a_{m+2}+ ( p+ \frac{1}{2})a_m - \frac{1}{4}a_{m-2}=0$
for $m≥2$

For $m=1$

$3a_3 + (p+ \frac{1}{2})a_1=0$

for $m=0$

$2a_2+ (p+ \frac{1}{2})a_0=0$

is this part a) correct?
how to solve part b) can you develop it step by step?
for $m=0$:

$2a_2+\left(p+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)a_0=0$
$a_2=-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(p+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)a_0$

dor $m=1$:

$3a_3+\left(p+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)a_1=0$

$a_3=-\dfrac{1}{3}\left(p+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)a_1$

for $m=2$:

$12a_{4}+\left(p+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)a_2-\dfrac{1}{4}a_{0}=0$

$a_4= \frac{1}{48}a_0+ \frac{1}{24} ( p+ \frac{1}{2})^2 a_0$

for $m=3$

$20a_5+(p+ \frac{1}{2})a_3- \frac{1}{4}a_1 =0$

$a_5= \frac{1}{80}a_1 + \frac{1}{120}(p+ \frac{1}{2})^2a_1$

Para $m=4$

$30a_6 + (p+ \frac{1}{2})a_4 - \frac{1}{4}a_2=0$

$a_6=- \frac {7}{240}(p + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{24}(p+ \frac{1}{2})^2a_0$

for $m=5 $

$42a_7+ (p + \frac{1}{2})a_5 - \frac{1}{4}a_3=0$

How is the term $a_7$? Are the calculations I have done for the other terms correct?
How do you end the exercise? what is the general solution?